# How to change the icon's 'on' state color?

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I am unable to change the icon's 'on' state color in Qt. I have the following test code:

header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QStyleFactory>
#include <QIconEngine>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
};
```

implementation file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QWidgetList allWidgets = qApp->allWidgets();
    for (QWidget* wid : allWidgets) {
        QString str = wid->metaObject()->className();
        if (str == "QPushButton") {
            auto btn = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(wid);
            if (!btn->icon().isNull()) {
                QIcon btnIcon = btn->icon();
                QPixmap pixOff = btnIcon.pixmap(QSize(1024, 1024));
                QPixmap pixOn = btnIcon.pixmap(QSize(1024, 1024));
                QPixmap pixDisOff = btnIcon.pixmap(QSize(1024, 1024));
                QPixmap pixDisOn = btnIcon.pixmap(QSize(1024, 1024));

                QPainter paintOff(&pixOff);
                paintOff.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
                paintOff.fillRect(pixOff.rect(), Qt::green);

                QPainter paintOn(&pixOn);
                paintOn.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
                paintOn.fillRect(pixOn.rect(), Qt::red);

                QPainter paintDisOff(&pixDisOff);
                paintDisOff.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
                paintDisOff.fillRect(pixDisOff.rect(), Qt::yellow);

                QPainter paintDisOn(&pixDisOn);
                paintDisOn.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
                paintDisOn.fillRect(pixDisOn.rect(), Qt::blue);

                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOff, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixDisOff, QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::Off);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOff, QIcon::Active, QIcon::Off);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOff, QIcon::Selected, QIcon::Off);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOn, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixDisOn, QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::On);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOn, QIcon::Active, QIcon::On);
                btnIcon.addPixmap(pixOn, QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);

                btn->setIcon(btnIcon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `.ui` file I add a few `QPushButton` and apply pixmaps as their icons:

[image: Form_File]

*From left to right: Disabled Button, Checkable Button, Non-Checkable Button.*

These buttons are placed in a checkable `QGroupBox` so that I can enable/disable them simultaneously.

When I run my code this is how it appears (the color for disabled is yellow so it is not much visible):

[image: Run_1]

Here the color for the middle `QPushButton` should be `Qt::red` since it is in checked (i.e. `QIcon::On`) state, but it is not red.

When I uncheck the groupbox, all the buttons becomes disabled and the icons change to `QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::Off`:

[image: Run_2]

The `QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::On` color is `Qt::blue`, and the middle button is in checked and disabled state, which means it should be blue but it is not.

The icons never change color to `QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On` or any other `QIcon::On` state. This means that the `QIcon::Off` state color is being applied correctly, but the `QIcon::On` state color is not being applied. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the value of [QPushButton::checkable()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop)? If `false` then this is normal (read doc).

Comment: BTW `if (auto btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(wid)) {`

Comment: The `QPushButton::checkable()` is true. I have multiple `QPushButton` some of them are checkable, some are non-checkable, some are in the disabled state. Each has its own icon.

Comment: Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @scopchanov the above is the minimal reproducible example. It is the entire CPP file, there is also the header file but it is the default. I will update my question to include all the details.

Comment: Much better! However, I still can't reproduce this with your code: _When I uncheck the groupbox, all the buttons becomes disabled and the icons change to QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::Off:_

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. But if your middle button is checked when you disable the groupbox then it should be in `QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::On` state which has `Qt::blue` as it's color.

Comment: @scopchanov I think you are getting the same behaviour as mine. Do your icons ever turn to red color when you check a checkable button?

Answer (score 1):

Preparing a **minimal** and **reproducible** example is always the right approach to solving the problem. Here is one that I have written for you and it is working:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *button = new QPushButton(tr("Click Me"), this);

        QPixmap pixOff(":/pix/images/save.png");
        QPixmap pixOn(pixOff);

        QPainter painter;

        painter.begin(&pixOn);
        painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
        painter.fillRect(pixOn.rect(), Qt::red);
        painter.end();

        painter.begin(&pixOff);
        painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
        painter.fillRect(pixOff.rect(), Qt::green);
        painter.end();

        QIcon icon;

        icon.addPixmap(pixOff, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
        icon.addPixmap(pixOn, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);

        button->setIcon(icon);
        button->setCheckable(true);
        button->setChecked(true);

        l->addWidget(button);
        l->addStretch();

        resize(200, 100);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** The example uses a 16x16 png-image from the resources. You should substitute it with your own image.

The example produces the following result:

[image: Checked state of a button]
[image: Unchecked state of a button]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it works but only in the default WindowsVista style. As soon as I apply Fusion style it stops working.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out it is a bug in Qt 5.15 versions: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86736

Comment: @Chaitanya, see, a [mcve] can really help identify the problem - the fusion style in your case.